# Stop using Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When coding iPhone applications, I've never used Interface Builder myself; thought it was too complicated and useless.

Problem is, I decided to pick up an abandoned opensourced project on GitHub which uses Interface Builder, and I can't seem to stop using it.

It seemed to be that I should start from scratch on programatically coding views, so I went to the application's `Info.plist` and deleted the `NSMainXIBFile` (or something like that) related keys.

Once I did so, the application launches, and a message is printed by the console: *Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch*.

I can't seem to find the issue here; I have done:

```
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:controller1, controller2, nil];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:controllers];
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Am I skipping some key step on stopping using Interface Builder or is my error at the code itself?

Comment: Just a comment: Coding the interface by hand is slower (development and runtime) without any real benefit.

Comment: While Interface Builder is handy for coding views, handling view controllers using it is complicated for me; I'd rather just keep it all in code.

Comment: If using IB is complicated for you then your architecture is probably suspect - IB is designed to work well with the way iOS expects you to do things.

Comment: What others have said, but more stongly.  If you aren't using IB, you are wasting your time (outside of very rare circumstance).  If it is taking you longer to use IB than write code, it is because you don't understand IB.  I've been using IB for 23 years and *every single time* I've worked on a project where someone avoided IB for such a reason, they were wasting their and their employer's time producing sub-optimal code.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't add the tab bar controller's view to the window as a subview. You should set it as the window's root view controller instead:

```
window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

Comment: How have you defined the window, is it set to the window property of the app delegate?

Comment: Yes, it is: `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;` and `@synthesize window = _window`. (`_window` is used instead of `window`)

Comment: Then what is the `window` you have in your code sample? It should either be self.window or _window if that is how you've declared the property.

Comment: I didn't use the `window` in my code itself; that was just some explaining at the question. (and I've even also tried `self.window`!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly assign the property `window.rootViewController`, not add the tab bar controller as a subview.

```
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@synthesize window = _window;


_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And then add a subview to the window.